# What is $x + O(x^2)$?

Tags: calculus, limits, asymptotics

Let $x \to 0$.

I wonder what is $x + O(x^2)$. I think it is $O(x)$, but I don't understand why is it true.

Is it also $\Theta(x)$?

And if it is $\Theta$ can I estimate it as $c \cdot x$?

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations) and [here](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/asymptotic-notation/a/big-o-notation).

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I know about it, but the case when $x \to 0$ really confuses me.

Comment: @Eff My mistake, i was thinking about $o(x)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say that $f(x)$ is in $\mathcal O(x^2)$, this means that
$$|f(x)| \leq c|x^2|$$
for $|x|<\varepsilon$ for some $\varepsilon>0.$

Hence, for $|x|<\varepsilon$, we have that
$$|x+f(x)| \leq |x|+|f(x)| \leq |x|+c|x^2|.$$

It is true that $|x^2|<|x|$ for $|x|<1$, so if $\varepsilon<1$, then
$$|x|+c|x^2| \leq |x|+c|x|=(1+c)|x|.$$

In conclusion, $x+\mathcal O(x^2)$ is in $\mathcal O(x).$

Comment: Just one question is $O(x^2) = o(x)$ as $x \to 0$?I think it is...

Comment: If $f(x)$ is in $\mathcal O (x^2)$, then
$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x} = 0$$
so: yes.